# Word formula field not displaying correctly in header

Tags: field, cpu-word

I am using formula fields in a document header to calculate and display the page numbering (current internal page count and total pages) for a section of the document. When the section is more than 100 pages long, the formula cuts off part of the page number starting around page 99 or 100 (see second table in screen shot below should be "Page 99 of 123"). The first and second table use the same formula. Notice when I remove the "current page" formula (as shown in the first table), the total pages displays correctly. Sometimes the "total pages" formula displays correct but when I run the "Update All Fields" macro in the document, the formula reverts back to cutting off part of the page number. I am using Word version 2102 (Build 13801.20864) - Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel. When I use Word version 2108 (Build 14326.20238), the "total pages" field displays the correct value. Is there a bug in Word version 2102 causing this issue?

Here is a link to the test document I created to demonstrate the problem.
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AophEWEj4pXjuXi2jo3arVB2M1nD?e=wczLak

[image: Header]

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Word version 2102 (Build 13801.20864) - Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel. It has been fixed with release of Version 2102: September 14 (Build 13801.20960).